# How to set Join for IQueryable<T> linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have done dynamic linq expression like below

```
private static List<Employee> FilterData(
    IQueryable<system> systemData, 
    IQueryable<employee> employeeData)
{
    var filterData = systemData.Join(
        employeeData,
        s => s.id, em => em.system_id, 
        (systemEntity, employeeEntity) => new { employee = employeeEntity});
}
```

> How to do below join when I use Generic in Join?
>   How to achieve s => s.id, em => em.system_id

```
private static List<TEntity> FilterData(
    IQueryable<T> systemData, 
    IQueryable<TEntity> employeeData)
{
    //var filterData = systemData.Join(
    //    employeeData,
    //    s => s.id, em => em.system_id, 
    //    (systemEntity, employeeEntity) => new { employee = employeeEntity});
}
```

Comment: Provided T and TEntity are type parameters to FilterData, you'll need to add generic constraints so that they are based on types that have id (for system) and system_id (for employee) defined

Comment: With IQueryable<system> the compiler knows the Properties from systemData... With IQueryable<T> the compiler cant known that T has a Property id or system_id

Comment: what will be the probable solution?

Comment: You either add constraints on the generic types that require them to have those properties (via an interface or base class), or you have to pass those lambdas to your method as expressions.

Comment: got you , any example for pass lambdas to method as expressions

Comment: Make a class which implements the Properties and inherit it on all classes on which you want to use the Method. So you are able to access the Properties through one Base class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add generic constraints to your method:

```
public interface ISystem
{
  int id { get; }
  ...
}

public interface IEmployee
{
  ...
  int system_id { get; }
  ...
}

private static List<TEmployee> FilterData<TSystem, TEmployee>(
  IQueryable<TSystem> systemData, IQueryable<TEmployee> employeeData)
  where TSystem : ISystem
  where TEmployee: IEmployee
{
  var filterData = 
      systemData.Join(employeeData,
                      s => s.id, 
                      em => em.system_id, 
                      (systemEntity, employeeEntity) => new { employee = employeeEntity});
}
```

note that it seems like you're only interested in getting the employees with an existing system_id, if that's the case, a Join is probably overkill (it would not if you extracted properties from the system)

Comment: hey thanks , what about I used direct model classes instead of Interface ?
like where TSystem : SystemTable
  where TEmployee: EmployeeTable

Comment: @Neo you can use either base classes or interfaces